# Dynamic order by in Paging SQL Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I would like to have paging & dynamic `orderby` clause in a stored procedure (THAT TOO ON MORE THAN ONE COLUMN). I did try following but gives me an error

It seems I cannot use Row_number() over rank()

> Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.

Is there any alternative to achieve this one, apart from linq to sql

```
SELECT  [t8].[AssetId], 
            [t8].[WorkOrderId], 
            [t8].[IssueDescription] AS [WorkOrderDescription], 
            [t8].[value] AS [Type], 
            [t8].[WorkOrderStatusTypeName] AS [Status],
            [t8].[value2] AS [StartDate], 
            [t8].[CompletedDate] AS [CompleteDate], 
            [t8].[value22] AS [CompletedBy], 
            ISNULL([t8].[value3],0) AS [Hours]
    FROM    (
                SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() 
                    OVER (ORDER BY  CASE WHEN @sortColumnName = 'default' THEN (RANK() over( order by [t7].[WorkOrderStatusTypeId] ASC, [t7].[WorkOrderId])) END ,
                                    CASE WHEN @sortColumnName = 'WorkOrderId' AND @sortOrder = 'asc' THEN [t7].[WorkOrderId] END ASC,
                                    CASE WHEN @sortColumnName = 'WorkOrderId' AND @sortOrder = 'desc' THEN [t7].[WorkOrderId] END DESC
                    ) AS [ROW_NUMBER],  
                    [t7].[AssetId], 
                    [t7].[WorkOrderId], 
                    [t7].[IssueDescription], 
                    [t7].[value], 
                    [t7].[WorkOrderStatusTypeName], 
                    [t7].[value2], 
                    [t7].[CompletedDate],
                    [t7].[value22], 
                    [t7].[value3]
            from    --Different tables      
            ) as t8     
    WHERE       [t8].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN ((@pageIndex-1) * @pageSize)+ 1 AND @pageIndex * @pageSize
    ORDER BY    [t8].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used

```
SELECT  CASE    
        WHEN @sortColumnName ='default' AND @sortOrder = 'asc'  then row_number() over (order by [t7].[WorkOrderStatusTypeId], [t7].[CompletedDate] ASC) 
        WHEN @sortColumnName ='WorkOrderId' AND @sortOrder = 'asc'  then row_number() over (order by [t7].[WorkOrderId] ASC) 
        WHEN @sortColumnName ='WorkOrderId' AND @sortOrder = 'desc' then row_number() over (order by [t7].[WorkOrderId] DESC)
        END AS [ROW_NUMBER],
```

Instead of

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY  CASE WHEN @sortColumnName = 'default' THEN (RANK() over( order by [t7].[WorkOrderStatusTypeId] ASC, [t7].[WorkOrderId])) END ,
                        CASE WHEN @sortColumnName = 'WorkOrderId' AND @sortOrder = 'asc' THEN [t7].[WorkOrderId] END ASC,
                        CASE WHEN @sortColumnName = 'WorkOrderId' AND @sortOrder = 'desc' THEN [t7].[WorkOrderId] END DESC
        ) AS [ROW_NUMBER],
```

Cannot have nested windowed functions like RowNumber() and Rank() together, instead they can be used inside case statement.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want a default order to be by two columns and you tried to use `RANK()` in an attempt to put both default sorting criteria in one CASE.

Apparently, that is not possible. One obvious option would seem to be splitting the two columns into two CASEs, repeating the `@sortColumnName = 'default'` condition:

```
ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (ORDER BY  CASE WHEN @sortColumnName = 'default' THEN [t7].[WorkOrderStatusTypeId] END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @sortColumnName = 'default' THEN [t7].[WorkOrderId] END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @sortColumnName = 'WorkOrderId' AND @sortOrder = 'asc' THEN [t7].[WorkOrderId] END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @sortColumnName = 'WorkOrderId' AND @sortOrder = 'desc' THEN [t7].[WorkOrderId] END DESC
```

On the other hand, it can be easily seen that the second and third CASEs could be merged into one, because the same expression is returned by both when the corresponding conditions are true. So, here's what you could do instead:

```
ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (ORDER BY  CASE WHEN @sortColumnName = 'default' THEN [t7].[WorkOrderStatusTypeId] END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @sortColumnName = 'default' OR @sortColumnName = 'WorkOrderId' AND @sortOrder = 'asc' THEN [t7].[WorkOrderId] END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @sortColumnName = 'WorkOrderId' AND @sortOrder = 'desc' THEN [t7].[WorkOrderId] END DESC
```

As you can see, the second CASE is used to set the ordering by `WorkOrderId ASC` both when that column is specified explicitly in the arguments and when `'default'` is specified.

Comment: +1 , problem still exists with having more than one column in order by clause in nested windowed function

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and thanks for posting your own version of a possible answer. I think you should consider removing it from the question and re-posting it as an answer instead, though, because it may so happen that you end up actually using it, in which case it would be absolutely fine if you accepted your own suggestion as the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score -1):

When creating a web API, the only way to do dynamic ordering, particularly on multiple colmuns, is to build the Sql string and run it using the built-in sprop 'SP_EXECUTESQL'. See below for my solution example, which returns a paged list, ordered by a string of multiple columns, and returns the total row count through an output parameter.

**Please not that when using strings directly concatenated like this, you must first check the parameters for sql injection of malicious code. Here I must check SearchTerm and SortTerm**

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Ranking_SearchForPlayerByName]
    @SearchTerm varchar(100),
    @WeekNumber int,
    @Gender nchar(1),
    @SortTerm nvarchar(100),
    @PageSize int,
    @PageNumber int,
    @TotalCount int OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

    DECLARE @PreviousWeek int = dbo.PreviousWeekNo(@WeekNumber)
    DECLARE @Offset int = (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize



    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'Select 
        h.PlayerID
        ,p.Forename as FirstName
        ,p.Surname as Lastname
        ,p.Gender as Gender
        ,''return country of residence'' as Country
        ,r.Name as Region
        ,h.Position as RankThisWeek
        ,previousWk.Position as RankLastWeek
        ,(previousWk.Position - h.Position) as Change
    From PlayerHistories h
        left outer join
            (Select * from PlayerHistories
                where WeekNumber = @PreviousWeek) previousWk on h.PlayerId = previousWk.PlayerId
        inner join Players p on h.PlayerId = p.Id
            left join Countries c on p.CountryId = c.Id
            left join Regions r on c.RegionId = r.Id
    Where h.WeekNumber = @WeekNumber And
        p.Gender = CASE When @Gender = ''M'' Then ''M'' When @Gender = ''F'' Then ''F'' Else p.gender End And
        p.FullName like ''%' + @SearchTerm + '%'' 
    Order by ' + @SortTerm + '
    OFFSET @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY

    '   
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Sql,
        N'@PreviousWeek int, @WeekNumber int, @Gender nchar(1), @offset int, @PageSize int', 
        @PreviousWeek, @WeekNumber, @Gender, @offset, @PageSize;

    SELECT @TotalCount = 
        (SELECT Count(h.Id)
        From PlayerHistories h
            left outer join
                (Select * from PlayerHistories
                    where WeekNumber = @PreviousWeek) previousWk on h.PlayerId = previousWk.PlayerId
            inner join Players p on h.PlayerId = p.Id
        Where h.WeekNumber = @WeekNumber And
            p.Gender = CASE When @Gender = 'M' Then 'M' When @Gender = 'F' Then 'F' Else p.gender End And
            p.FullName like '%' + @SearchTerm + '%');


END
```

Test calling this using the statements below:

```
DECLARE @op int

exec dbo.usp_Ranking_SearchForPlayerByName 'smith',201715,'','LastName DESC, Gender, FirstName',10,1, @op OUTPUT

select @op
```

Comment: This is not maintainable. What if columns were removed or renamed? You will only find out when client starts losing money.