# Any advantage of a stored procedure *with* dynamic SQL inside vs just dynamic SQL C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

**Question**

I find myself needing to write a stored procedure with paging AND dynamic sorting ([where case statements won't do](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029044050/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/010704-1.shtml))

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877894/dynamic-order-by-in-paging-sql-query) seems to be the only option, however at this point, is there any good reason for it to be a stored procedure at all? Will there be any real benefits, presumably it won't be pre-compiled in any useful way?

Therefore I am more tempted to simply do it as dynamic SQL within the C# code itself, and skip the complexity of using a stored procedure (and I feel it would actually be *more* readable in a C# built up string) but will this be noticeably slower then using a stored procedure.

And for extra intrigue, is this an area where EF would actually be quicker / the same, as surely really all its doing is building dynamic SQL? (See Background)

**Background**

Most of our database code is written with stored procedures (as in 90%) but there is this small sliver of code written in Entity Framework. I have been asked to replace EF with stored procedures as this area of code has been identified as a bottleneck and they wish to optimise it. As a fan of EF, I want to push back on the optimal point but as a fan of consistency I didn't originally see any reason not to harmonise this 10% with the other 90%....now I do, the operation in question involves paging AND dynamic sorting!

Comment: alternatively can I was considering loading in a dummy stored procedure, to improve readability (as it could be opened in SQL server), then replacing the relevant parts, but I feel the dummy SP might be confusing to others

Comment: That external link is bad; it only mentions `sp_ExecuteSql` once, with zero examples, when that is exactly the thing you **should be using** if you're doing dynamic sql at the DB

Comment: @chrispepper1989 Voting for close because the question is too subjective. In brief - if you feel more comfortable with EF, it makes more sense to use it, since a good LINQ query is more likely to perform better than a poorly written SP. On the other side, it seems that your team prefers to use SQL and generally, a well written SQL at worst will give the same performance as EF and a lot of times will outperform EF by a lot (just google EF vs pure SQL). Also I've seen developers pushing towards EF just because they don't know SQL.

Comment: @Leron sorry for confusion, EF is only mentioned as background, this isnt a SP vs EF question, more a is SP dynamic SQL better then *just* dynamic sql, which is a pure performance question and not subjective

Comment: So just as a "its always worth pushing back" story, I found out that actually the multiple order by has never actually been used, the data has always been sorted by one column in the UI and there is no plan to change the UI. So I was able to do a standard SP with a CASE order by :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Advantages

Advantages of SQL in a stored procedure are:

- abstraction, you could refactor the database without changing the .net application
- security, you could have better security checks by setting correct execution rights. Also you could limit the dataset do security aware information isn't outputted.
- transparency: which queries are executed to the database?
- optimizations of the query query, use the correct index etc.

### Downsides

Downsides of dynamic SQL in stored procedures:

Dynamic SQL (in SQL server) could be tricky with security and performance.

#### Security

SQL server has less "tools" to prevent injection. Variables could not be used everywhere and so only if you hardcode all order by options, then you are safe. But with dynamic filtering, this could be difficult.

e.g. this is safe:

```cs
posts = context.Posts  
    .FromSql("SELECT * FROM mytable")
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreateDate)
```

This is unsafe (yes, there are better ways to write this):

```
declare varchar(200) @orderby = 'createDate DESC'

SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER by + '@orderby

EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

So you need to list all options or check all options.

#### Performance

Performance wise there **could** be problems with dynamic SQL in stored procedures. A stored procedure which returns very dynamic data, 
could choose the wrong query plan with sub optimal performance.

`*` You could recompile every stored procedure call, but that has also it downsides.

### Table value functions

Another option is to use table value functions (TVF). Those are more limited than stored procedures, but they return a table which you could page and sort.

Those have the advantages of stored procedures as described above, but not the downsides of dynamic SQL in the database!

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-use-table-valued-user-defined-functions

#### Example TVF and EF Core

There is a nice example of table value functions and EF,

.NET Core with TFV GetMatchingPostByTitle

```cs
posts = context.Posts  
    .FromSql("SELECT * FROM dbo.GetMatchingPostByTitle({0})", searchTerm)
    .Where(p => p.BlogId == 1)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreateDate)
    .ToList();
```

Will generate this SQL:
[image]

More details [here](https://cmatskas.com/entity-framework-core-1-0-table-valued-functions-and-linq-composition/)

Comment: "SQL server has less "tools" to prevent injection" - it has `sp_executesql`, which is a pretty versatile tool really; it can be used to fully parameterize inner-sql, avoiding all risk of injection (assuming you aren't allowing arbitrary tables names etc as input! i.e. things that wouldn't be parameters in the inner-sql)

Comment: E.g. It's hard to check there is no SQL injection in your table name, or in the order by or where clause (expect hard code all options for the order by). You can't use parameters for that.

Comment: If you query uses a `in`, you have a problem?

Comment: I'm not saying dynamic SQL equals injection. Only that the validation is more limited and more work.

Comment: @Julian this is a great answer, thank you, I am not familiar with table functions at all and will have to do some more in depth research, but I think this answers my question as fully as it could :) . Could I ask, when you say "which you can page and sort" is that still within SQL rather than in code?

Comment: The table value function cannot sort, but it will return a table and you could do a `select * from tableValueFunction() order by X`. You it's really between a query to a table and a stored procedure. So the ordering query is written in C# and performance in SQL Server. Hope that make things clear :)

Comment: Will add an example.

Comment: @Julian sorry one more thing, as you dont list it am I right to assume there is no real performance difference between the dynamic SQL in code and the dynamic SQL in Stored proc? Because I am starting to wonder if its even worth the teams time to rip out the EF which im assuming gets the same performance as dynamic SQL in code

Comment: Per injection: It's significantly easier to set up a robust whitelist in C# than it is in a stored proc. Obviously, if everything is parameterized or internal, that's moot.

Comment: Re "in" - that's what things like `string_split` are for - although personally I'd let a tool like Dapper or EF worry about those details

Comment: @Julian, thank you for such a brilliantly detailed answer!